# Usage of "loggerheads" in a contest question

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I'm wondering what does "loggerheads" mean in this sentence and why has it been used this way.
This is one of the sentences in which one needed to fill the gap with the best matching word in one of the popular English contests.

*Irritable and quarrelsome, Walker was soon at _ _ _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ with all his neighbours.*

So, the Wikidictionary says that a loggerhead is an obsolete way of calling someone stupid, it doesn't match this sentence at all.

DeepL translator translated loggerheads as "conflict" which is way batter translation but I'm still confused with this word. What does it actually mean in this context?

Comment: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=loggerheads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idiom "at loggerheads"  (the idiom always uses the preposition "at" and the plural form)

If two people are "at loggerheads", it means they are in conflict and neither person is able to make progress.

> Tim and Janie have been at loggerheads over the design of the front cover.  Tim wants photograph and Janie wants a simple geometric design.  Unless one gives way, the cover won't be ready when we want to print the book.

Dictionary source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loggerheads

Wiktionary : https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_loggerheads#English

Comment: Oh, it's an idiom, I was looking for a word instead, I will be more careful next time. Thank you!